# Advice on optimal way to learn more math

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics

I live in the US, I'm in my early 50's, worked in Wall Street for 25 years and retired from that life early this year, with no intention to go back. My dream is to dedicate the rest of my life to learn as much mathematics as I can. I have a BA in economics and an MBA. My BA involved a decent amount of math. Early this year I was admitted to an MA in Mathematics from an OK institution, their math program ranks in the middle in the US.Beauty of this MA is you can do it 100% online and I live in the countryside. So far I have taken three courses, differential equations, history of math and analysis. Straight As in all three. I know my question is very generic but any advice would be highly appreciated. Should my goal be getting a PhD? I think I'm a great math teacher because I love them so much and particularly love teaching students who don't like them or think they are too boring or too hard, but who wants a novice math teacher in their late 50s? Should I just finish my MA and go for an MSc? Thanks and all the best.

Comment: You should try posting this on the Math Educators Stack Exchange: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Teaching is much more than knowing the material. Life experience, together with many other skills and qualities, can be just as important. Just because you may not be as experienced in teaching mathematics as some of your colleagues, this doesn't mean you can't be a good teacher.

Comment: Do you want to teach or do research?  A phd is not strictly necessary to teach.  If you want to do research, then it's worth thinking about.
Fwiw, I'm 40, and a first year phd student in pure math at a top 40ish US program.  Like you, I had a career on wall street and moved to the mountains a few years ago, decided I wanted to do math, so moved to a university town and started taking classes.  I think spending time at a university (not online) could help you decide if being a student suits you (it's not for everyone, and has plenty of aggravations).

Comment: I don't think we can tell you what _your_ goal should be. If you just want to learn math, like you said, then you can figure out yourself how _you_ learn best, whether it's enrolling in a degree program, buying some books and working through them, using free online classes, etc. If you want to do something besides for _learning_ math, you'll have to tell us what that is.

Comment: One of the best math teachers I had went back to school when her children were grown. // It's too soon right now for you to know how far you want to go; you can see how it goes as you go along. // So glad to hear you're enjoying yourself.  Have fun!

Comment: @Blue-FootedBooby'sBlueFeet: Even at Math Educators Stack Exchange, this question would probably be put on hold for the same reason it has been here.

Comment: Thank you all. I wasn't aware of the rigidity of what is appropriate or not to ask on this exchange. For what is worth, some of the answers above are already helping me, so if helping is they the goal, perhaps less rigid rules, or rule  interpreters, would give participants a better chance to be helped. Bamboo, good luck with your PhD, unfortunately right now physically moving to a university is not a possibility for family reasons. The university I am attending is a large state university, it just offers some of their courses and programs online. And thanks aparente001, that's encouraging.

Comment: Hi, I'm 17 and my advice: Read a book, or if you just want to do recreational for fun, try this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions